# How to properly build a CRA project to support IE11?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, create-react-app

I'm working on a project that needs to support IE11.

We are using `create-react-app`.

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Given the fact that IE11 is such an old browser, does it even make sense to add anything else to the `browserslist` config?

Couldn't I just do this?

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Also, if I'm building targeting `ie 11` do I also need to add `react-app-polyfill` ?

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that this:

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    "ie 11"
  ]
}
```

Will remove many useful prefixes like `-webkit-`.

So, you should use:

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "ie 11",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

About the polyfills, you definitely need to add them as well.

[image]

From the image above, you can see that babel will transpile the arrow function `() => {}` to a syntax compatible with IE 11, but you can also see that `Object.assign`, `Promise` and `URL` will all need polyfills to work on older browsers that don't natively support them.

Here [react-app-polyfill/ie11](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-app-polyfill/ie11.js) you can see all the polyfills that are added for IE11.